# Collapse and sum total corresponding values

Tags: microsoft-excel

hoping I explain this correctly:

I have a large spreadsheet like the one below

[image: spreadsheet]

I need to collapse multiple rows (with the same order number) and total the individual cost prices into a single total

Comment: Have you tried the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the table, go to insert and then click on "Pivot Table", this will create a new worksheet for you with this information.

Once you have done this, place the Order Number column into the "Rows" section and the Total Cost column into the "Values" section -

Like in this screenshot
[image]

and it should give you what you needed.